# Why do I only get the last value of a for loop in view in django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Lets say:

```
y = [go, cat, jump, see]
```

if i did:

View:

```
  for x in y:
      x
```

template:

```
   {{x}}
```

I would only get the x=see and no other result, 1. why is that? 2. How can I make it work?
I know doing it in the template works but i need to also look up some values for each item in the array or dicitonary (unless, that could be done in the template too). Any  thoughts?

Edit.
So I have this: session = {4,5,6,7,}
 which is saved in a session, it comes from a form full of check box choices, those are all primary keys.

views:

```
 form = inlinefactory_formset(model1, model 2,extra = len(sesssion)
 formset = form(instance=None )
```

in my views I have this

```
{% for x in session%}
    {{x}} {{formset}}   
    {%endfor%}
```

So it prints the number and a form for the number. That is almost what I want, the x is a pk like i mentioned above, I want to use that pk to look up the name for the x instance and print that with the form so that people know what form they are editing.

Comment: Please show us bigger pieces of code. What variables are you passing in the context?

Comment: thanks for at least asking form more instead of voting it down like everyone else

Answer (score 1):

I think in your views you are doing,

```
for x in y:
   print x
```

then you are render the context like this,

```
render(request, "some.html", {"x": x} )
```

But above only takes last value.

Do this way,

```
render(request, "some.html", {"y": y} )
```

in your template,

```
{% for x in y%}
    {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop x is updated. So after it has run the value of x is the last value in the list.

What you want to do is loop through it in the template:

```
{% for x in y %}
   {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```